# Moment js diff string

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Lets assume we have two dates in Javascript, 2019-05-01 and 2019-05-23. What is the most efficient way to produce a diff string with moment.js (or native JS date) which looks like:

```
1 - 23 May 2019
```

The solution should also work in different months and years, like:

2019-05-01 and 2019-06-12

```
1. May - 12. June 2019
```

2018-05-01 and 2019-06-12

```
1. May 2018 - 12. June 2019
```

Basically only the date parts should be displayed which are different in a human readable format. Is there something inbuilt in moment as making a new function with a couple of if conditions does look not the right approach for me? It basically should work for every command. I'm pretty sure that I'm not the first one with this issue and there is a helper function in moment, something like

```
moment('2019-05-01').calculateSpan('2019-06-12').format('D MMMM YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Date1 = moment(new Date("2018-04-01"));
const Date2 = moment(new Date("2019-05-23"));

/**
 * @return {string}
 */
function ReadableDate(date1, date2) {
    let month = "";
    let year = "";
    if (date1.month() !== date2.month()) {
        month = date1.format("MMM")
    }
    if (date1.year() !== date2.year()) {
        year = date1.format("YYYY");
    }
    return date1.format("D") + (month && ". ") + month + (year && " ") + year + " - " + date2.format("DD MMM YYYY");
}



let str = ReadableDate(Date1, Date2);
```

Read more about [moment formatting](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: This does not work with the dates 2019-05-01 and 2019-06-12 as it should print then 1. May - 12. June 2019. The solution should work in general that only the diff is displayed and the parts which are the same only once without knowing what is different, I'v updated my question.

Comment: ok, so you want to show the month if they are not the same and the year if they are not the same?

Comment: Yes exactly, basically show the parts which are different and the ones which are duplicated only once. So Date2.format("DD MMM YYYY") would produce for both strings 1. May 2019 and 23. May 2019 but I want only the parts which are different and the ones which are duplicate only displayed once. I was hoping for some support from moment and that I don't have to do the diff by myself.

Comment: That's what I was coming up too. But I hoped for something in moment itself, like moment('2019-05-01').calculateSpan('2019-06-12').format('D MMMM YYYY'); where calculateSpan is a function which holds two objects and allows to use the moment date commands to print the span as format.

Comment: I searched moment js docs, I couldn't find anything related to custom functions, but if you did you can add this function as a custom function! anyway if this function helped you achieve what you request. please mark this answer as the correct one!

Comment: This solution will not work for times. I'm looking for a general approach which will work for any command and not something hardcoded.